# LeftSideMenu in MFSideMenu not responding

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm implementing [MFSideMenu](https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu) in my project and this is my AppDelegate Code :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    
    MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController
                                                    containerWithCenterViewController:[[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                                                       initWithRootViewController:[[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil]]
                                                    leftMenuViewController:[[SideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SideViewController" bundle:nil]
                                                    rightMenuViewController:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = container;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

The menu appear correctly and all of it's contents but the components inside it (button, tableview, etc...) not responding to any interaction . I've created a new clean project and add the menu only on it but with no hope.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if you use the leftMenuVC (SideViewController)  as the  window's root, skipping the MFSideMenu thing completely?  Does user interaction work then?  i.e. `self.window.rootViewController = [[SideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SideViewController" bundle:nil]`

Comment: Also, can you paste the simple project someplace?

Comment: @danh yes it does. and yes I can past it it's not more than two empty viewControllers !

Comment: So I did what you did:  new project, add two view controllers (MainVC and SideVC).  Put a menu open button in Main.xib and a do nothing button in Side.xib (the action method just NSLogs).  Copied (in essence) your app delegate code.  Launched and ran properly the first time, including a log message from the side menu button.

Comment: Sorry - the file sharing thing didn't work.  Here's a new link:  http://www.filedropper.com/mfmenuoxxy

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

SideViewController *leftMenuVC = [[SideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SideViewController" bundle:nil];

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController
        containerWithCenterViewController:[[UINavigationController alloc]
        initWithRootViewController:[[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil]]
        leftMenuViewController:[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:leftMenuVC] rightMenuViewController:nil];

self.window.rootViewController = container;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```